# Getting comments for a post by certain users in Django using Postgre

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have two models `Post` and `Comment`. My users are able to build friendships with one another. I want to write a method that from a certain queryset of posts if the user's friends have commented on that post it will by consuming as less memory as possible.

My models are:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(1200)])
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(350)])
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

now assuming I have a list of user id's which are friends with `request.user`

By: `friends = Friend.objects.friends(request.user)`

and I have a queryset of posts:

`posts = Post.objects.select_related("author").filter(author__in=friends).order_by('-date_posted')`

I can get the comment id of each post by: `post.comments.values('id').select_related('author').filter(author__in=friends).order_by('-created-on')[:2]`

However, if I want to do this for hundreds of post it will be extremely expensive. How can I get the last two comments by a users friends from each post as fast as possible by using the least memory?

Comment: Why do you use `.values()` and not fetch the comments itself?

Comment: I thought gettings id's and then doing other steps would make the process faster, but for instance, if I want to do it without a for loop I do not know how to achieve that @WillemVanOnsem